# Selection of elements from numpy array columns based on row index

Tags: python, numpy, search, indexing

I have a bidimensional array `A` and a list of indexes `idx`, for example :

```
A = np.array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
             [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
             [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
             [ 0., -1.,  0.],
             [ 0.,  0.,  5.]])

idx = np.array([2, 1, 0, 1, 2])
```

and I'm trying to select the elements of `A` indexed by `idx` along the column axis (in this example : `array([0., 1., 0., -1., 5.])`). How can I do this without loops ?

Thank you !

Comment: Why do you not want to use loops? - This could easily be solved with a `for` loop.

Comment: @Alfie because numpy is usually extremely faster than for loops.

Comment: @Alfie As @Luca said, numpy operations are extremely more efficient than loops in Python, and on top of that the matrix `A` has huge dimensions in my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
A[np.arange(np.size(idx)), idx]
```

gives `array([ 0.,  1.,  0., -1.,  5.])`

From the [Advanced Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) part of the documentation:

> When the index consists of as many integer arrays as the array being
>   indexed has dimensions, the indexing is straight forward, but
>   different from slicing. [...] This is best understood with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing 2D numpy arrays can be a bit confusing.

You need: `A[np.arange(0, A.shape[0]), idx]`